# *Not* able to get values back from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, casting

The values in file:

```
[232, 413]
[4645, 233]
[2.1, 6.234]
```

Code I am using

```
f = open('doze.txt', 'r')
xa=[]
for x in f.readlines():
   x.split()
   ta=[]
   i=int(x[1])
   j=int(x[4])

   ta=[i,j]
   xa.append(ta)
print(xa)
f.close()
```

Getting error for typecasting.
Tried using `if` to separate numbers, but it did not work.

Output I get:

```
[2,4], [4,2], [2,6]
```

The output I need:

```
[[2, 4], [4645, 233], [2.1, 6.234]]
```

All the values in int/float form.

Comment: `x.split` returns something. You never use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's how the data in your file is formatted—like Python literals—you could use the [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function to do it easily like this:

```
import ast

xa = []
with open('doze.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        row = ast.literal_eval(line)
        xa.append(row)

print(xa)  # -> [[232, 413], [4645, 233], [2.1, 6.234]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing split values anywhere , also the values read from file 'doze.txt' are in string format from which you should replace unrequired symbols and parse needed data . For type conversion , you can use int(x[0]) or float(x[0]) as required .

```
    f = open('doze.txt', 'r') 
    xa=[]  
    for x in f.readlines():
       x = x.replace(']','').replace('[', '').replace(' ', '').replace('\n','').split(',')
       print(x)
       i=x[0]
       j=x[1]
    
       ta=[i,j]
       xa.append(ta)
    print(xa)   
    f.close()
```